# SQL Server Profiler: why the RPC Starting event does use an different decimal separator from SP Starting?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, profiler

Trying to diagnose an problem, I've ran into that inconsistency.
In SQL Server Profiler, the `RPC Starting` event uses the regional settings to write real numbers (example: in Portuguese(Brazil) 14.5 will be expressed as 14,5).
Normally that's not a problem, except where the RPC call is a stored procedure with real number parameters. So what is expected to be expressed as:

```
exec usp_something 'blabla', 14.5
```

Is expressed as:

```
exec usp_something 'blabla', 14,5
```

Which gives a lot of headaches when you have a long parameter list.
Didn't find any clue online how to change that behavior.

Someone knows a way to change that behavior?

Btw: I'm aware that the workaround is to use `SP Starting` event instead, which uses '.' for decimal separator.

Comment: Do you also see this with an Extended Event trace of `rpc_starting` events? I suspect this is a bug but, given Profiler/SQL Trace are deprecated, it might not get much attention.

Comment: @Dan :All logins' default language are English. SQL Server Profiler version: 10.0.1600.22

Comment: @Dan: OS language is portuguese (both client and server)

Comment: Yeah. That might be the reason. I bet if you create a new OS (for testing) with English version you will not see the strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Starting SQL Server 2008, Microsoft has introduced Extended events. It can be used instead of SQL trace; maybe it does not have this bug. Here is the simplest code to create one:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [NewSession] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed
```

It is more readable and easy to understand.
Paul Randal has a great [article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/converting-sql-trace-to-extended-events-in-sql-server-2012/). It describes how to convert your SQL trace to a new session (Extended Event)